# ADO DevOps - Sprint Capacity Issue when parallel releases are happening. I need the dashboard to pick it separately

Tags: azure-pipelines, ado

the sprint capacity widget in the ADO dashboard is picking up patch release as well when two releases are going parallelly. Any solution to rectify it?

The result was that I am only getting sprint capacity result of one release